# zIndex tap event

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have an app that has a panel with default zIndex: 0. This panel is collecting x,y coordinates when user taps on this panel. When certain coordinates are matched there is an sub item within this panel that pops in which has zIndex:2. While this second panel is active it is obstructing the full view of the zIndex:0 panel underneath. During this stage this second panel takes taps that are intended for panel below.

I need to be able to collect taps only on zIndex:0 panel. Any taps on zIndex:2 panel should be ignored or passed to panel underneath it. How do I make zIndex:2 panel to ignore any taps and have only zIndex:0 panel to respond to taps?

Any help much appreciated.

```
// coordinates panel
xtype: panel,
zIndex: 0,
items:[
   {
     // second panel
      xtype: panel,
      zIndex: 2
   }
]
```

Comment: Is that working for you: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#8GC3J

Comment: This is also an interesting read on this topic: http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/22/css-pointer-events-to-allow-clicks-on-underlying-elements/

Comment: Thanks TDeBailleul. That "pointer-events: none;" worked perfect.

Comment: Ok, I'll add this as an answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the CSS attribute `pointer-events: none` on the second panel

Read this article for further information: [CSS pointer events to allow clicks on underlying elements](http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/22/css-pointer-events-to-allow-clicks-on-underlying-elements/)

Hope this helps